# On duplicate gives syntax error and does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add products to a database from an XML file and when there's a duplicate `article number` I want to just update the `stock` level.
I'm still learning PHP and MySQL and I've read numerous post on this forum but I just can't get it to work.

So what I did is this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("a-link-to-downloaded_products.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

  foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {
      $article_code = $row->artikelnummer;
      $brand = $row->merk;
      $name_nl = $row->naam;
      $ean = $row->ean; 
      $stock = $row->voorraad_aanwezig; 

      $sql = "INSERT INTO `products` (article_code,brand,name_nl,ean,stock) VALUES ('" . $article_code . "','" . $brand . "','" . $name_nl . "','" . $ean . "','" . $stock . "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `stock` = VALUES(`$stock`)";

      $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      ..... etc .....
  }
```

Above gives me an error saying

> Unknown column '1' in 'field list'

or

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1)' at line 1

Because of that second error I assume that it has something to do with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stock = VALUES($stock)"` However I tried a lot of different variations but I just can't get it to work! I used backticks, quotes etc. Almost anything I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `stock` = VALUES(`$stock`)
```

With:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `stock` = VALUES(`stock`)
```

Explanation: the `VALUES()` construct in the `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` clause is used to reference a column value that is passed in the `INSERT` clause.

Important note: anyone on SO will tell you that you should really consider using [prepared statement and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), in order to make your queries safer and more efficient.

Comment: Ok to be sure... `VALUES('stock')` references to the column name `stock` in my db? About that security issue... I'll have a look into that, for now it's just something I'm trying to learn so this is my very first PHP project :) Anyway it works perfectly.... I understand now that "1" in the error since I tried to look for a column name "1" instead of stock.

Comment: @Meules: VALUES(`stock`) (with backticks, not single quotes) references the value that was originally given for INSERT in column stock. For more information you can have a look at [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).